# Angular2. How can I use *ngFor for set "URL" in the tag "href" and set '{{theme.name}}' in the condition *ngIf?

Tags: angular, ngfor

I need switching templates.
I have 12 css files need to be loaded dynamic

I have a template html. It's works for example (hardcode):

```
<div class="container">
    <link rel='stylesheet'   href="/app/switchTemplate/css/amelia/bootstrap.min.css" *ngIf="currentTheme.name === 'amelia'" />
</div>
```

When I use <*ngFor="let theme of themes"> for tag "href"
It's not worked (dynamic)

```
<div class="container">
    <link rel='stylesheet'  *ngFor="let theme of themes"  href="{{theme.url}}" *ngIf="currentTheme.name === '{{theme.name}}'" />
</div>
```

How can I use *ngFor for set "URL" in the tag "href" and set '{{theme.name}}' in the condition *ngIf?

Answer (score 7):

You can't have more than one structural directive on a single element.
You can use a `<template>` tag but the new `<ng-container>` element is more convenient because it works with the same syntax as structural directives on normal elements:

```
<div class="container">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let theme of themes">
    <link rel='stylesheet'    href="{{theme.url}}" *ngIf="currentTheme.name === theme.name" />
  </ng-container>
</div>
```

The `<template>` or `<ng-container>` elements are only processed internally by Angular2 and never added to the DOM.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response.

Comment: But I have error:
<blink>
zone.js:355 Unhandled Promise rejection: Failed to load app/switchTemplate/templates/%7B%7Btheme.url%7D%7D ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Failed to load app/switchTemplate/templates/%7B%7Btheme.url%7D%7D undefined
</blink>
I see that is not correct set the href value.
I don't understand, why is not set the correct value?

Comment: I didn't look fare enough to the right of your code. `*ngIf="currentTheme.name === '{{theme.name}}'"` should be `*ngIf="currentTheme.name === 'theme.name'"`. Don't use `{{}}` inside binding expressions when `[]` or `*` is used on the attribute.

Comment: Thanks.
When I delete to the right of my code <code>    <ng-container *ngFor="let theme of themes">
        <link rel='stylesheet' href='{{theme.url}}' />
    </ng-container> </code>
Anyway, I have this error.
I see that href equal: "app/switchTemplate/templates/%7B%7Btheme.url%7D%7D"

Comment: @Дмитрий Ерушенко And also don't use `''` within `'theme.name'` expression. And seems you need to use property binding for `href` together with `DomSanitizer` https://plnkr.co/edit/deimCC3vqnUTdHErtPXC?p=preview